# F# create instance method for a constrained generic parameter

Tags: f#

Is it possible to have an instance method of a class which only works when the generic type is restricted to a particular type?

For example, I want to define an `Add` method which only works when the contained type is `float`. Here's the closest I've gotten but I'm unsure how to constrain the `'Value` type to `float` in the member `_.Add` signature. Right now I get an error on the next to the last line saying the type of `'Value`  cannot be resolved at compile time. Can I restrict this method to only apply when the type of `'Value` is `float`?

```
type ImArr<[<Measure>] 'Index, 'Value>(values: array<'Value>) =
    // We want to make sure we have our own copy to protect against mutation
    let values = values |> Array.copy

    member internal _.Values : array<'Value> = values

    member this.Item
        with get(index: int<'Index>) =
            values.[int index]


type Arr<[<Measure>] 'Index, 'Value>(values: array<'Value>) =
    // We want to make sure we have our own copy to protect against mutation
    let values = values |> Array.copy

    member this.Item
        with get(index: int<'Index>) =
            values.[int index]

        and set(index: int<'Index>) (value: 'Value) =
            values.[int index] <- value

    member internal _.Values : array<'Value> = values

    // This is the method I would like to constrain to only be used when the
    // type of 'Value is float
    member _.Add (b: ImArr<'Index, float>) =
        if values.Length <> b.Values.Length then
            invalidArg (nameof b) "Cannot add arrays of different lengths"
        // TODO: Turn this into something using SIMD intrinsics
        let mutable i = 0
        while i < values.Length && i < b.Values.Length do
            values.[i] <- values.[i] + b.Values.[i] // <-- Error here
            i <- i + 1
```

Comment: Did you see my answer to your previous question?

Comment: I did. Thank you.

Comment: I think this is essentially the same problem, but to answer your direct question: No, it is not possible. If you define a generic type, such as `Arr<'Value>`, then its instance members have to work for any valid `'Value` type chosen by the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @brianberns in the comments, not directly. However, [C#-style extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/type-extensions#extension-methods) can be defined for a specialized version of a class. The caveat is that as an extension method, it won't have access to private members.

```ml
[<Extension>]
type ArrExtensions =

    [<Extension>]
    static member Add (this: ImArr<'Index, float>, b: ImArr<'Index, float>) =
        if this.Values.Length <> b.Values.Length then
            invalidArg (nameof b) "Cannot add arrays of different lengths"
        // TODO: Turn this into something using SIMD intrinsics
        let mutable i = 0
        while i < this.Values.Length && i < b.Values.Length do
            this.Values.[i] <- this.Values.[i] + b.Values.[i] // <-- Error here
            i <- i + 1

// When the namespace containing the above type is opened,
// the following can be called:

floatArr1.Add(floatArr2)
```

Comment: This is cool. I didn't know it was allowed. Thank you.